# Setting default model value depending on a scenario

Tags: php, yii2

I can't sort out why setting default value doesn't work for me.

Here is my controller:

```
class QueryController extends ActiveController

{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Query';
    public $createScenario = 'restCreate';
    public $updateScenario = 'restUpdate';
```

I don't override the default `createAction` method.

Model:

```
 class Query extends ActiveRecord 
{public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['userId', 'name', 'created', 'isOneTime', 'isArchived', 'settings', 'engine'], 'required'],
        [['userId'], 'integer'],
        [['name', 'settings', 'schedule'], 'string'],
        [['created', 'lastUpdate'], 'safe'],
        [['isOneTime', 'isArchived', 'isApi', 'valid'], 'boolean'],
        [['state', 'engine'], 'string', 'max' => 160],
        [['isApi'], 'default', 'value'=> false],
        [['isApi'], 'default', 'value'=> true, 'on' => 'restCreate']
    ];
} 
public function scenarios()
    {
            $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
            $scenarios['restCreate'] = ['name', 'state', 'isApi', 'isOneTime', 'settings', 'schedule'];
            $scenarios['restUpdate'] = ['name', 'state', 'isOneTime', 'settings', 'schedule' ];
        return $scenarios;
    }
```

When I create a new entry via a Rest controller, it should set `isApi = true` by default, but it doesn't work in a such way. How can I assign a default model values depending on scenario?

Comment: Default values in the model rule is applied when field is empty. I dont think it prefills the fields.

Comment: @ck_arjun, okay so i should post it through form and set it like a `$this->isApi = ''` Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should swap this rules:
`[['isApi'], 'default', 'value'=> false]`
`[['isApi'], 'default', 'value'=> true, 'on' => 'restCreate']`

You must do this because `DefaultValueValidator` appling only one time for single field. This validator run only if field's value is empty. There is this check: [\yii\validators\DefaultValueValidator::validateAttribute()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/validators/DefaultValueValidator.php#L46)

Model runs  validators one by one. `[['isApi'], 'default', 'value'=> false]` sets value for field to `false`. `[['isApi'], 'default', 'value'=> true, 'on' => 'restCreate']` see that value is not empty and skipped.

Answer (score 1):

Yii uses only fields from current scenario. By default it sets in `\yii\base\Model::SCENARIO_DEFAULT` (`default`). Default scenario contains all fields from rules without `on` attribute.

If you want to use custom scenario, you must set it. You can do this by two ways:

1. By constructor.
   `$model = new Query(['scenario'=>'restCreate']);`
2. By setter.
   `$model = new Query();`
   `$mosel->setScenario('restCreate');`

See [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios) for more information about scenarios.

**P.S.** Good practice is using constants as scenario names. It help you make fewer mistakes in names of scenarios. For example:

```
class Query extends ActiveRecord {
    const SCENARIO_REST_CREATE = 'restCreate';
    const SCENARIO_REST_UPDATE = 'restUpdate';

    public function scenarios()
    {
        $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
        $scenarios[static::SCENARIO_REST_CREATE ] = [/*...*/];
        $scenarios[static::SCENARIO_REST_UPDATE ] = [/*...*/];
        return $scenarios;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your examples, I've read this part of documenation before posting here. Since my controller `extends ActiveController` there are predefined public properties `$createScenario` and `$updateScenario` which allows to set scenario in my controller bu this code `public $createScenario = 'restCreate';
    public $updateScenario = 'restUpdate'; ` http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-activecontroller.html#$createScenario-detail

Comment: @IvanNosyrev Май инглиш из вери бэд.  Я не совсем понял, у вас вопрос какой-то остался? Или вы просто объяснили, почему не используете константы?

Comment: вопрос остался тот же что и в сабже. Вопрос не про константы, и не про то как засеттить сценарий. Вопрос в том, что поле не принимает дефолт значение из rules.

Answer (score 0):

In your action :

```
public function ActionCreate(){
$model->scenario = 'restCreate';// it will set your scenario first .
 //remaining code for write here
}
```

Comment: It is not necessary to do it in a such way. Setting public properties `public $createScenario = 'restCreate'; public $updateScenario = 'restUpdate';` should be enough.

Comment: then it will applied on all action and you can't default value accurate.