# Yii2 - Assign a "fix" condition

Tags: yii2, yii2-model, yii2-validation, yii2-active-records

I am building an app, where an account can have many services, all the information is related to a service. In example:

Account A has 3 services and each service has pages.

In order to avoid someone modifying the service_id when saving a page, at the moment I do:

```
if(Yii::$app->request->isPost) {

    $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
    $model->load($post);
    $model->service_id = $this->service->id;
}
```

Where $model->service_id = $this->service->id helps me assign the selected service_id after loading table to model and avoid someone sending service_id from the form.

But in case someone in the future, develops "documents" I would like to avoid the developer handling this service_id on all the queries.

So First it I thought I could try:

```
public function beforeFind($queryData) {
    parent::beforeFind();
    $queryData['conditions'] = array('service_id' => 2);    
    return $queryData;
}
```

But still needs the developer to implement it. So maybe is there a way to create a "BaseService" model where all other service related models should extend from but not sure how to:

1. Add the condition from the parent model?
2. How to pass the id to this model so it keeps it during all queries?

Maybe there is a simple solution, and I am overcomplicating myself due long hours working, not sure.

Answer (score 3):

That is a default condition to apply for all queries. In case your application is built on top of [ActiveRecord](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record) classes *(not performing direct SQL queries or on the fly [QueryBuilder](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder))* then you can simply override the `find()` method inside your Model class:

```
public static function find()
{
    /* you can add more dynamic logic here */
    return parent::find()->where(['service_id' => 2]);
}
```

By default, all controllers in Yii2 are using `Model::find()` to retrieve data from database, adding such condition should be enough to not retrieve anything with a different `service_id` than 2. Direct http GET requests by ID should then output 404 if that condition isn't satisfied and retrieving them as relational data within a different model class should return a filtered array.

**IMPORTANT:** To not break that implementation you need to:

1. Always use
   [ActiveRecord](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record). Otherwise you'll need to manually add the condition to your queries.
2. **(This is not correct)** <strike>Be carful on when to use **asArray()** as it omits ActiveRecord features *(See [note and explanation
   here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#data-in-arrays))*. Otherwise you need to manually re-declare the condition like: `Account::find()->where(['service_id' => 2])->asArray()->all();`</strike>
3. Always use **andWhere()** to merge conditions because **where()** will override/ignore the default one. Example: `Account::find()->andWhere('age>30')->all();`

Comment: Second point is incorrect, `asArray()` will work perfectly fine with conditions defined in `find()`, since it does not affect query itself.

Comment: Corrected. I guess I've been avoiding using it all this time for no reasons then. Thank you for pointing it out @rob006

Answer (score 0):

to reuse such filters you can put them into a [custom ActiveQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948917/yii2-activequery-example-and-what-is-the-reason-to-generate-activequery-class).

in your ActiveRecord:

```
public static function find() {
    return (new ActiveQuery(get_called_class()));
}
```

ActiveQuery:

```
public function service($service = 2) {
    return $this->andWhere(['service_id' => $service]);
}
```

your model based on your ActiveRecord:

```
public static function find() {
    return (new ActiveQuery(get_called_class()))->service(2);
}
```

alternatively

```
$model->find()->service(1);
```

also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34345314/setting-default-model-value-depending-on-a-scenario) might be of interest (setting Default values per scenario)